# Fuse ESB mysteriously hangs - "JVM appears hung: Timed out waiting for signal from JVM."

Tags: java, jvm, freeze, nagios, fuseesb

My `Fuse ESB` application suddenly stopped, with no clues in `fuseesb.log` and the following weird log items in `wrapper.log`:

```
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 02:36:59 | JVM appears hung: Timed out waiting for signal from JVM.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 02:36:59 | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 02:37:02 | JVM exited in response to signal SIGKILL (9).
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 02:37:02 | Unable to start a JVM
STATUS | wrapper  | 2014/02/12 02:37:02 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

We are using Nagios to monitor the system.

System info: FuseESBEnterprise-7.1.0 / linux-gnu (x86_64).

For various reasons we need to sick with Fuse ESB (not possible to migrate to JBoss Fuse...)

Comment: Our sysadmin tells me they had problems with vmware, and that's probably why it stopped. The lesson learned is that the wrapper.log file should be added to the monitoring system (nagios), since it is in this file that `ERROR` is logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a system issue - the vm hung.

You can catch this kind of condition in one of two ways:

1. monitor the java jvm process
2. monitor the wrapper.log file for errors